# Add annotation to programmatically added child resource via resource builder

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am programmatically adding child resources via the resource builder and need the resulting resource method to have the PermitAll annotation present.
Is this possible using some jersey API?

Comment: [Check out a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43793385/2587435).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! I realized that the Inflector's apply method can also be annotated and will be properly processed by my authorization request filter.

Answer (score 1):

So, with my request filter checking for PermitAll annotation on the resource method, I relaized I can annotate the Inflector.apply() method directly to make the request filter work without modifying it.

```
resourceBuilder.handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>() {

                            @Override
                            **@PermitAll**
                            public String apply(ContainerRequestContext data) {
                                // ...
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't know you could do that!